# Individual months in WP Query

Tags: wp-query

I would like to create `WP_Query` query and I am using [date parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters). How should I should write my query if I want to get all posts from: January 2019 and May 2019 (there is not range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to pass multiple sets of arguments to `date_query`, so if you set `relation` to `OR` for them, you should get posts that match either, meaning that you could get the posts you want like this:

```
'date_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [
        'month' => 1,
        'year'  => 2019,
    ],
    [
        'month' => 5,
        'year'  => 2019,
    ],
],
```